# How can I make html files available in Wildfly tmp directory?

Tags: html, spring, gradle, jboss, wildfly

I am working with Exclipse, Spring, Angular js, Gradle build project and using jboss-wildfly server to deploy and run in local machine. My issue is the tmp folder under C:\server\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp does not contain any of my html and js files.

I would need those file while working with GUI design, as we can make changes and directly see it browser without building and deploying the war again.

How can I make my html files available in tmp directory? pls help

Comment: it is exploded war i am speaking about :) it is not available under my tmp folder while running wildfly

Comment: If it's an exploded WAR you shouldn't need to worry about the tmp directory. Are you using JBoss Tools or some other IDE?

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE. Did some research and added below lines in standalone.xml. I am able to see exploded under 


\wildfly-.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp435bb60737c345a8\content-f0db2ae47f000478\WEB-INF\jsp path.
 But it is not reflecting when i make changes to jsp files in this path and refreshthe webpage.

 <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-exploded="true" deployment-timeout="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>